# Can't find a solution to eliminate second record type within Lookup

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

Within my CRM instance is the core entity 'Case'. Within this is the default customer lookup (customerid) which points to both the core 'Account' & 'Contact' entities. There is also another lookup pointing to 'Contact' which is filtered based on the Account value in customerid (it is essential that customerid is used to select just account values). There is also another lookup pointing to a custom entity, which uses a auto number function. I am trying to also filter this field (new_projectref) to show just records associated with the account value selected. However a Error is being thrown stating "'Contact' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'customerid'.".

```
/* Filter Lookup */

function preFilterLookup() {
  try {
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_projectref").addPreSearch(function () {
      addLookupFilter();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    //window.console.log("Prefilter lookup error " + error.message);
  }
}

function preFilterLookupGeneric(sourceField, destinationField) {
  try {
    Xrm.Page.getControl(destinationField).addPreSearch(function () {
      addLookupFilterGeneric(sourceField, destinationField);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // window.console.log("Prefilter lookup error " + error.message);
  }
}

function addLookupFilterGeneric(sourceField, destinationField) {
  try {
    var companyId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(sourceField).getValue()[0].id;
    var entityType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue()[0].entityType;
    alert(entityType);
    if (entityType == "account") {
      console.log("Company = " + companyId);
      if (companyId != null) {
        fetchXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='customerid' operator='eq' value='"
          + companyId + "' /></filter>";
        Xrm.Page.getControl(destinationField).addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
      }
    } else if (entityType == "contact") {
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    window.console.log("Error lookup filter " + error.message);
  }
}

function addLookupFilter() {
  try {
    var companyId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentaccountid").getValue()[0].id;
    //  window.console.log("Company = " + companyId);
    if (companyId != null) {
      fetchXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='customerid' operator='eq' value='"
        + companyId + "' /></filter>";
      Xrm.Page.getControl("new_projectref").addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // window.console.log("Error lookup filter " + error.message);
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please edit you title to be more descriptive, because looking at the title no one will try to help you out

Comment: And have you ever heard of line breaks ?

Comment: I indented the code for you, please take the time to do this next time. You have to make it easy for people to help you!

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, pretty new to stack overflow so was unsure of the 'Best practices', I shall take your advice on board next time.

Answer (score 0):

`customerid` is the name of the attribute on the Case entity.  If you want to apply the filter against an account or contact field you need to update the fetchXml to use the id of the account entity which is `accountid` or `contactid` for Contact.

`"<filter type='and'><condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' value='" + companyId + "' /></filter>";`

Comment: Only problem being that if I change this to account id, the error message appears again but instead states that the custom entity doesn't contain the attribute? I think my only option left is to replace this multi entity lookup field with a custom lookup just pointing to the Account entity.